# Error while creating spark session

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datastax

I am trying to connect to DSE 5.1 cluster using the spark session. I am getting the below error when using the cluster url.However if i set the master to localhost it all works fine.

```
SparkSession.builder().appName(getClass.getSimpleName).master(""spark://10.10.10.10:1010"") >>> error.
SparkSession.builder().appName(getClass.getSimpleName).master("localhost") >>
```

Works fine.

Stack trace of the error:

```
17/05/05 12:44:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/05 12:45:23 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
17/05/05 12:45:23 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
17/05/05 12:45:23 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
17/05/05 12:45:23 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
java.lang.InterruptedException
```

Comment: Looks like [connectivity issues](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/connectivity_issues.html)

Comment: is ur master UI responding ???

Comment: Yes the master web UI is responding.Also the job gets picked up by the master but fails resource allocation to the workers